# What is the cost of mmaping on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, performance, mmap

I have an algorithm where my life would be greatly simplified if I could reserve about 20 blocks of memory addresses of size 4GB. In practice, I never use more than 4GB, but I do not know which block will fill up in advance.

If I `mmap` 20 blocks of 4GB everything seems to work fine -- until I write to memory the OS does not seem to actually allocate anything.

Is there any reason I should not use `mmap` to allocate 80GB of memory, and then only using a small amount of it? I assume there is some cost to setting up these buffers. Can I measure it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only drawback of mmap-ing 80GB at once is that a [page table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_table) has to be created for the full 80GB. So if the pages are 4kB, this table could consume a lot of memory (unless [huge pages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_(computer_memory)#Huge_pages) are used).

For sizes like that it is probably better to use one or more *sliding* mmap-ed views (i.e. create and remove them when needed).

On Windows, memory usage for mmap/page tables can be checked with [RamMap](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/rammap), not sure about Mac.